# Run ZFS as non-root

Tags: zfs, mount, fstab, zfsonlinux

I'm running Debian 10 in a VM (using KVM) and I want to use ZFS as a non-root user. Here is what I did.

I added this line to my sources.list file

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
```

Here is my complete sources.list file

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
```

I installed ZFS

```
sudo apt install zfs-dkms zfsutils-linux -y
```

Then during the installation I got the following error

```
Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems
```

And I resolved my problem by running

```
sudo /sbin/modprobe zfs
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

I added the following line to the `/etc/modules`

```
zfs
```

There is 2 disks connected to my VM :

- /dev/sdb
- /dev/vda

I created a pool

```
sudo zpool create -f mypool mirror /dev/vda /dev/sdb
```

See my `zpool list`

```
$ sudo zpool list
NAME     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
mypool  9.94G   291K  9.94G         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

And my `zpool status`

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: mypool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    mypool      ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        vda     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Then I tried to delegate ZFS permissions. 
So I added a new user :

```
sudo adduser zfsuser
```

I changed the permissions of `/mypool/`

```
sudo chown zfsuser:zfsuser /mypool -R
sudo chmod u+rwx /mypool -R
sudo chmod go-rwx /mypool -R
```

Then I gave the permissions

```
sudo zfs allow -u zfsuser create,destroy,mount mypool
```

Here is the result of `zfs allow mypool`

```
$ sudo zfs allow mypool
---- Permissions on mypool -------------------------------------------
Local+Descendent permissions:
    user zfsuser create,destroy,mount
```

But when I log as `zfsuser`

```
su zfsuser
```

The user isn't able to mount even if I gave the permission in a previous command

```
$ /sbin/zfs create mypool/test
filesystem successfully created, but it may only be mounted by root
```

What am I missing ?
Should I edit my fstab file to allow zfsuser to mount ? How should I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to ["Possible Workarounds for Inability to Mount as non-root under Linux #10648"](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/10648).

`zfs create` and `zfs clone` won't work right now.